# Date to weekday on Python 3.6.1

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a thing that converts a date, that the user chooses, into a day of the week and have tried to use calendar.weekday, but that doesn't work and everything else I've found on the internet doesn't work either, so I could use a little help. The biggest problem is to let the user fill in the date...

This is what I made myself:

```
import calendar

def date(year, month, day):
    y = year
    m = month
    d = day


#take input form the user
print("Vul in welke datum je wil gebruiken")

while 1:
    d = int(input("Vul de dag in: "))       
    m = int(input("Vul de maand in: "))        
    y = int(input("Vul het jaar in: "))
    calendar.weekday(y, m, d)

print(calendar.weekday(y, m, d))

if (calendar.weekday(y, m, d)) == '0':
        print("Maandag")
if (calendar.weekday(y, m, d)) == '1':
        print("Dinsdag")
if (calendar.weekday(y, m, d)) == '2':
        print("Woensdag")
if (calendar.weekday(y, m, d)) == '3':
        print("Donderdag")
if (calendar.weekday(y, m, d)) == '4':
        print("Vrijdag")
if (calendar.weekday(y, m, d)) == '5':
        print("Zaterdag")
if (calendar.weekday(y, m, d)) == '6':
    print("Zondag")
```

The problem is that it doesn't give me an answer, is there another formula I should use, or is there another problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
import datetime 

userInput = input('Write the date in quotations (space-separated, year, month, day): ')
userInput = list(map(int, userInput.split(' ')))
day = datetime.date(userInput[0], userInput[1], userInput[2])
print(day.weekday())
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it gives an error:Write the date (space-separated, year, month, day): 02 09 2000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/A Python/Weekdag datum probeer.py", line 5, in <module>
    day = datetime.date(userInput[0], userInput[1], userInput[2])
IndexError: list index out of range